# Runtime Error 5 in VBA: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, runtime

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "RReal+RCEmin" 
Dim UltimaFila As Long 
Dim RangoDatos As String 
UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 
RangoDatos = "RReal+RCEmin!R1C1:R" & UltimaFila & "C9" 
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=RangoDatos, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="RReal+RCEmin!R1C15", TableName:="D1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion8
```

I have tried to create the table using every version but it does not work.

Comment: Does the error persist if you remove `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion8` and `Version:=xlPivotTableVersion8`?

Comment: yes, the error persist

Comment: Then, by process of elimination, something is wrong with `RangoDatos` or `"RReal+RCEmin!R1C15"` or `"D1"`.

Comment: I've fixed this type of error in the past by splitting the pivotcache and pivottable creation into different steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your sheet names within single quotes...

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim UltimaFila As Long
Dim RangoDatos As String

SheetName = "RReal+RCEmin"

ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName

UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

RangoDatos = "'" & SheetName & "'!R1C1:R" & UltimaFila & "C9"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=RangoDatos).CreatePivotTable tabledestination:="'" & SheetName & "'!R1C15", TableName:="D1"
```

Here's another way...

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim RangoDatos As String
Dim UltimaFila As Long
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

SheetName = "RReal+RCEmin"

ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName

UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

RangoDatos = "'" & SheetName & "'!R1C1:R" & UltimaFila & "C9"

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=RangoDatos)

Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, tabledestination:="'" & SheetName & "'!R1C15", TableName:="D1")
```

As you can see, it creates the PivotCache and the PivotTable in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range directly without having to construct the range address

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
Dim UltimaFila As Long, rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Name = "RReal+RCEmin"

UltimaFila = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:I" & UltimaFila)

Set pc = ws.Parent.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                      SourceData:=rng)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Range("O1"), _
                             TableName:="D1")
```